# How to specific rows from a split list in R based on column condition

Tags: r, subset

I am new to R and to programming in general and am looking for feedback on how to approach what is probably a fairly simple problem in R.

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(county = rep(c("QU","AN","GY"), 3),
                 park = (c("Downtown","Queens", "Oakville","Squirreltown",
                          "Pinhurst", "GarbagePile","LottaTrees","BigHill", 
                          "Jaynestown")),
                 hectares = c(12,42,6,18,92,6,4,52,12))
df<-transform(df, parkrank = ave(hectares, county, 
           FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")))
```

Which returns a dataframe looking like this:

```
 county         park hectares parkrank
1     QU     Downtown       12        2
2     AN       Queens       42        1
3     GY     Oakville        6        1
4     QU Squirreltown       18        3
5     AN     Pinhurst       92        3
6     GY  GarbagePile        6        2
7     QU   LottaTrees        4        1
8     AN      BigHill       52        2
9     GY   Jaynestown       12        3
```

I want to use this to create a two-column data frame that lists each county and the park name corresponding to a specific rank (e.g. if when I call my function I add "2" as a variable, shows the second biggest park in each county).

I am very new to R and programming and have spent hours looking over the built in R help files and similar questions here on stack overflow but I am clearly missing something. Can anyone give a simple example of where to begin? It seems like I should be using split then lapply or maybe tapply, but everything I try leaves me very confused :(

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If any of the answers suit you, please indicate so but "accepting the answer" (press that green tick next to the answer), or even vote up for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
df2  <- function(A,x) {
  # A is the name of the data.frame() and x is the rank No
  df  <- A[A[,4]==x,]
  return(df)  
}

> df2(df,2)
  county        park hectares parkrank
1     QU    Downtown       12        2
6     GY GarbagePile        6        2
8     AN     BigHill       52        2
```

Comment: Hmm it's more probable that the OP means this one. +1

Comment: Thank you so much @user1945827